# Java - Calling a paintComponent Method

Tags: java, swing, object, methods, paintcomponent

I would like to have a circle that can be recreated by calling its method with the given x,y,color parameters. But i'm having difficulty in doing so. I want to use JComponent as an object rather than a component.

```
public class OlympicRingsComponent extends JComponent {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.translate(10, 10);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(7));

    Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(0,0,100,100);

    g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
    g2.draw(circle);

}}
```

this code works fine. But i would like to be able to call a method in order to create a new ellipse.

```
public class OlympicRingsComponent extends JComponent {

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.translate(10, 10);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(7));

    ring(10 , 20 , "Blue");

}
public void ring(int x , int y , String color) {
    Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double( x , y ,100,100);

    g2.setPaint(Color.getColor(color));
    g2.draw(circle);
}}
```

Comment: I think that at least you should pass g2 object to ring() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add `graphics2D` argument to `ring()` method like this:

```
public void ring(int x , int y , String color, graphics2D g2) {
    Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double( x , y ,100,100);

    g2.setPaint(Color.getColor(color));
    g2.draw(circle);
}
```

and call `ring()` with the `graphics2D` argument:

```
ring(10 , 20 , "Blue", g2);
```

I think that should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. Though, how could I access it from a nother class? say,    OlympicRingsComponent r = new OlympicRingsComponent(); r.ring(10 , 20 , "Blue", g2);

Comment: @Neoaptt: That's a different question.  Generally, you create a class with a draw method for drawing the object created by the class.

Comment: you can call the `repaint()` method on the `OlympicRingsComponent` object. It will internally call the `paint()` method with appropriate `Graphics` object.

    `OlympicRingsComponent r = new OlympicRingsComponent();`
    `r.repaint();`